# How to select make the default value of all my variables '0' when only nulls are being returned?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am running into issues where my conditional statements don't work because I am doing comparisons (at times for certain situations) where I'm comparing a null with an integer. I tried using an exception but after printing the variable values onto my display i found out that this exception only handled 'NO_DATA_FOUND' error messages. Is there a way I can get the variable to get a '0' selected into it in the case a 'NULL' or BLANK is returned? Below is my code:

```
SELECT MAX(VALUE)
  INTO VARIABLE_1
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'HI';
SELECT MAX(VALUE)
  INTO VARIABLE_2
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'BYE';
---
EXCEPTION 
 WHEN no_data_found
 THEN SELECT 0
      INTO VARIABLE_1
      FROM DUAL;
      SELECT 0
      INTO VARIABLE_2
      FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need a whole `select into` query just to assign a value to a variable. PL/SQL has an assignment operator `:=`, e.g. `variable_1 := 0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nvl()` to provide a default value:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(VALUE), 0)
  INTO VARIABLE_1
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'HI';

SELECT NVL(MAX(VALUE), 0)
  INTO VARIABLE_2
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'BYE';
```

The `no_data_found` exception won't be raised because you're using an aggregate function; that will always return one row, even its value is null. A null value is not the same as no rows being returned.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `coalesce`

```
SELECT coalesce(MAX(VALUE), 0) AS value
  INTO VARIABLE_1
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'HI';
SELECT coalesce(MAX(VALUE), 0) AS value
  INTO VARIABLE_2
  FROM VALUE V
  JOIN REL_VALUE RV on V.value_id = RV.value_id
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND FIELD_TX = 'BYE';
```

Answer (score 1):

use nvl command for it like :
nvl(column_name,0).